# how to make radio button checked in adapter?

Tags: android

In my case I have radio buttons in a list view. Only one radio button can be selected at one time. My code is working fine.

**Problem:**
I want to make radio button checked if its checked value is one in my list.
i have tried many methods but I haven't found a solution yet. Following is the code part for radio button from the adapter class:

**Adapter.java**

```
   if(mpref.GetquestionType().equals("Radio")){

        h.radio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        h.radio.setText(data.get(position).answere);
        if(data.get(position).checked.equals("1")){
           /*What should i do there...*/
        }
        h.radio.setTag(position);
        h.radio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                Log.i("ID of radiobutton","Order Edit @ position : " + pos);
                if (position != mSelectedPosition && mSelectedRB != null) {
                    mSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
                    ((VasNBIActivity) context).removeChecked(data.get(mSelectedPosition).id);
                    mSelectedRB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_ackgroun1);
                    /*data.get(mSelectedPosition).checked="0";*/
                }
                mSelectedPosition = position;
                ((VasNBIActivity) context).addChecked(data.get(mSelectedPosition).id);
                h.radio.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background);
               /* data.get(mSelectedPosition).checked="1";*/
                mSelectedRB = (RadioButton) v;
            }

        });
        if (mSelectedPosition != position) {
            h.radio.setChecked(false);
        }else {
            h.radio.setChecked(true);
            if(mSelectedRB != null && h.radio != mSelectedRB){
                mSelectedRB = h.radio;
            }
        }
```

In `removeChecked` and `addChecked` I am adding selected radio button ID to array list for submitting. Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: have u list of Array for adapter

Comment: Just add check of items count in the data binding `getView()`. If size = 1 then check it

Comment: if you need help, show all the important things in your adapter, your question is very ambiguous, maybe answering your serf this questions will help you, what Kind of Adapter are you using?, what is mpref?, what kind of container is h?, whay you are trying to save a position inside radio.setTag()? and the most important What class is radio?, looks like maybe is not a regular radio button, Do your definition of your Adapter contains direct or indirect access to Context?

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar yes i have array list